# How to show form in UpdateView on Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I want to make Update page which change User of model information.
My program is berow.

```
#urls.py

url(r'^user_edit/(?P<pk>\d+)$', views.UserEdit.as_view(), name='user_edit'),



#models.py

from datetime import datetime
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User    

class User(User):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='Null')
    post = models.CharField(max_length=9, default='Null')
    bank = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='Null')
    mail = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='Null')
    address1 = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='Null')
    address2 = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='Null')
    address3 = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='Null')
    tel = models.CharField(max_length=15, default='Null')
    fax = models.CharField(max_length=15, default='Null')


#views.py
from .forms import InvoiceForm, UserForm, CustomerForm ,UserSignupForm
class UserEdit(generic.UpdateView):
    model = User
    form_class = UserForm
    template_name = 'invo/user.html'
    success_url = "invo/user_info"

    # get current user object
    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        return self.request.user

#forms.py

from django import forms
from .models import Invoice, User, Customer

class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ["username", "email",'password','first_name', 'last_name', ]

#user.html [Template]

{% extends 'invo/base.html' %}

{% block content %}


<div class="gtco-section gtco-testimonial gtco-gray">
    <div class="gtco-container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 gtco-heading text-center">
                <h2>Update</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <h3>User Profile</h3>
            <div class="row">
                {% if messages %}
                <ul class="messages">
                    {% for message in messages %}
                    <li
                    {% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message }}</li>
                    {% endfor %}
                </ul>
                {% endif %}
                <form method="post">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <table>
                        {{ form.as_p }}
                    </table>
                    <input type="submit" value="change">
                </form>


            </div>


        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- END .gtco-services -->


{% endblock%}
```

My page is like this.It doesn't have forms
[image]
This is html source code.There is Form.But it's hidden!! What is problem? Didn't get form information...?

```
#source

    <h3>User Profile</h3>
            <div class="row">

                <form method="post">
                    <input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='pLoy7OtBOunF70avjFRTt1wlaIwTIArfe8wkNmbVZOslAu6G4hiFoC8oRWVhcbID' />
                    <table>

                    </table>
                    <input type="submit" value="change">
                </form>
            </div>
```

I made another Update Form same way.But User model cannot show form.
If you know about this problem.Please Help me.

Comment: You haven't shown where `UserForm` is defined.

Comment: I checked import . But UserForm was imported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think its probably your model fields, you are inheriting the User model and trying to change its field, It would be safer to inherit the AbstractUser class. That could be the cause. If you don't know how to use the AbstractUser class you can checkout this tutorial. https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html, I really hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! AbstractUser was worked well! This source cord was effect for me.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26954694/updating-custom-user-model-in-django-with-class-based-updateview

Comment: I think maybe (UserChangeForm) is also important on forms.py

Answer (score 0):

Using class-based views, you can instead specify just the fields on the model to use, and a ModelForm will be generated, so long as the view can work out which Model the view is for. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#model-forms

Then your view could look like:

```
class UserEdit(generic.UpdateView):
    model = User
    fields = ('username', )
```

Comment: And did you remove the `form` attribute?

Answer (score 0):

you have defined form_class as user edit form but you are using {{ form.as_p }} as form in the template correct it first